# UITableView and delegates

Tags: objective-c, delegates, uitableview

I have an iPad app in progess but I'm having difficulty catching the selection of a row in my table view. I know this is because I haven't defined my delegate properly yet but, after 2 hours on the net, it still isn't making much sense.
What I'm trying to do is pass the selected table row item to a new view that displays info based on the selection - pretty standard.
I set up the tableViewController sub class using the option to create it as a UITableViewController subclass which, unless I am wrong, incorporates the delegates (UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource) automatically.

In the didSelectRowsAtIndex method I'm trying to create a DetailViewController. I've tried with a nib file and creating one purely in code but the class is never created. I'm missing a step I'm sure of it but I can't find what it is. At some point shouldn't I be defining what function I want to access with the selected row? But where? How?

In what I considered was my best attempt, I created the DetailViewController, set a string variable in the detailViewController to the selected row, and then tried to add the detailViewController view to display. I figured I could then use the viewDidload to call the next function but the view never got displayed on screen.

Some basic guidence would be nice. Or a decent tutorial would be nice. No calls to read the relevant docs please, I've been over it and right now I need a example to pull things together.
Thanks,
Steve

Comment: Consider editing your question and posting the code of what you’ve tried so far.

Comment: Not sure what I did to fix this but I deleted what I had done and tried it all again. Pretty sure I didn't change anything major but the delegate is now calling the viewDidLoad of the class. Frustrating...

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, maybe paste the code snippet will be easier to figure out what's going on here.  And are those delegate(didSelectRowAtIndexPath:) methods being called correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing this line in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method

```
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

where controller is an object of class `DetailViewController`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

this goes in didSelectRowAtIndexPath

```
 MoreInfoTable *moreInfoView = [[MoreInfoTable alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
//in the MoreInfoTable, make properties like titles etc.
[self.navigationController pushViewController:moreInfoView animated:YES];
[moreInfoView release]; 
}
```

here's an example of an MoreInfoTable.h

```
   @interface MoreInfoTable : UITableViewController {
NSMutableArray *moreInfo;
NSURL *getDirections;
NSURL *getWebsite;
NSMutableString *getPhoneNumber;
NSString *address;
NSString *footer;
float lat, lon;


}
-(void)goToWebsite;
-(void)goToMaps;
-(IBAction)addToFavorites:(id)sender;
-(void) callNumber;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSURL *getDirections;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSURL *getWebsite;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableString *getPhoneNumber;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *footer;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *address;
@property (readwrite) float lat;
@property (readwrite) float lon;
@end
```

now back in the other file in which you declare the table, you can say

```
MoreInfoTable *moreInfoView = [[MoreInfoTable alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
//in the MoreInfoTable, make properties like titles etc.
moreInfoView.title = @"TITLE!";
//etc. 
[self.navigationController pushViewController:moreInfoView animated:YES];
[moreInfoView release];  //
```